# SerialPort QT C++ data sensor

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a program to collect data from an IMU sensor through a SerialPort

The data of the IMU received via the software of the latter are in Hexadecimal

So I would like to extract them in Hexadecimal too in a first time

You will find attached my program, the problem is that I receive 0 at each data reception.

```
static const int FRAME_SIZE = 68;

Imu::Imu() :
    moving(false)
{

    serialPort = new QSerialPort("COM3",this);
    if (!serialPort->open( QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        log_warning("imu","failed to open device file \"%s\", IMU measures will be unavailable",qPrintable(serialPort->portName()));
        return;
    }

    if (!serialPort->setBaudRate(115200))
        log_error("imu","failed to set baudrate, error no %d",serialPort->error());
    serialPort->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop); // One Stop bit
    serialPort->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

    pollingTimer = new QTimer(this);
    QObject::connect(pollingTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(pollSerialPort()));
    pollingTimer->start(10);

    }

Imu::~Imu()
{
    serialPort->close();
}

void Imu::pollSerialPort()
{
    static const unsigned char START_BYTES[2] = {0x55,0xAA};
    static const QByteArray START_WORD((char*)START_BYTES,2);

    static QTime startTime = QTime::currentTime();
    static QByteArray data;
    data.append(serialPort->readAll());
    qDebug() << data.count() << data.toHex();
```

Comment: What's the output of `qDebug() << data.count() << data.toHex();`?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback; the output is zero

Comment: Why are you polling the `QSerialPort` rather than connecting to its [`readyRead`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qiodevice.html#readyRead) signal?  Or, indeed, any of the other signals that might notify you of a state change and/or error condition?

Comment: I asked QserialPort because the Imu is directly used at a  SerialPort, 

I am a beginner in QT (since a few days), so I don't know yet how to use the readyRead.

Can you help me on this please
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Define two slots in your `Imu` class, one to read data and another to handle error condition, then connected them to `errorOccurred` and `readyRead` signals of `QSerialPort` like this.

```cpp
serialPort = new QSerialPort("COM3",this);
connect(serialPort, &QSerialPort::errorOccurred, this, &Imu::handleError);
connect(serialPort, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &Imu::readData);
```

When data arrives on serial port, Qt will automatically call `readData` slots. In `readData` you can get all the data like this

```cpp
void Imu::readData() {
    const QByteArray data = serialPort->readAll();
    qDebug() << data.count() << data.toHex();
}
```

In `handleError` function, you can check different error conditions:

```cpp
void Imu::handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError error)
{
    if (error == QSerialPort::ResourceError) {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

**Side Note:** Don't use old style signal/slot connection, use new style. Below link provides nice explanation.

https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer,

I have done the readyread, however this time, I had no data reception. Not even the 0 that I had at the beginning.

Is it necessary to declare the connections in this way? and/or to add functions in the file.h .

Is the QByteArray appropriate for reading serialport knowing that it returns data in Hexadecimal

Thanks a lot

Thanks again for your reply.

```
QObject::connect(serialPort, &QSerialPort::errorOccurred, this, &Imu::handleError);
QObject::connect(serialPort, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &Imu::pollSerialPort);


}

Imu::~Imu()
{
   serialPort->close();
}

void Imu::handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError error)
{
    if (error == QSerialPort::ResourceError) {
   // qDebug()<<"handleerror" <<;
    }
}


void Imu::pollSerialPort()
{
    static const unsigned char START_BYTES[2] = {0x55,0xAA};
    static const QByteArray START_WORD((char*)START_BYTES,2);
    static QTime startTime = QTime::currentTime();
    if (!pollingTimer->isActive()){
            pollingTimer->start(10);
    }
    static QByteArray data;
    data.append(serialPort->readAll());
    qDebug() << data.count() << data.toHex();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Looks like there is a mismatch in the serial port settings between source and destination. Use docklight or any other software to check if you are really receiving the data from the device.